# BMP 280 exact Altimeter readings

Tags: arduino-uno

I was just going through this [pressure sensor tutorial](https://iknowvations.in/arduino/pressure-sensor-bmp-280-arduino-tutorial/).

What I want to know is how can I set the exact altimeter in my readings depending upon my different geographical place ? or may be if I am attaching the sensor to my balloon.

Comment: If you can know an exact height at the start of the sketch (or maybe just assume 0m for start), you could save the starting pressure in setup(), then use that pressure (converted from Pa to hPa) to calibrate the loop() altitudes.

Answer (score 3):

The tutorial sample source code has the line:

```
Serial.print(bmp.readAltitude(1013.25)); // this should be adjusted to your local forcase
```

That `1013.25` value should be the local pressure at sea level in hundreds of Pa. If want to show altitude above ground level, you will need to know that for your location and write your code to calculate the altitude offset.

The sensor can't know location -- it only measures pressure. The AdaFruit library provides the altitude conversion, but being generic, it relies on several assumptions.

Comment: The baromic pressure is at sea level. Every wheather station compensates the measured value. First of all, you have to know the height of the sensor. Start with a height map: http://www.ahn.nl/index.html and add something for how high the sensor is in your house. The Adafruit library https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_BMP280_Library/ does not have a function to correct the height. This is too complex: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barometric_formula This is simple: http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/barometers-elevation-compensation-d_1812.html It is +7hPa for 61 meters.

Comment: What units is the output given as?

Comment: @DavidGlass Again, the Adafruit library example source code has a following line that indicates the unit is Meters.