# 6-pin BME280 not giving I2C signal

Tags: esp8266, c++, i2c

[image: Updated picture]

I'm creating a telemetry package for my my mom's model rocket with a MPU6050, a BME280, and a SD reader/writer. The code I found for the BME does not read any information. When I upload an I2C scanner, the MPU gives a signal, but the I2C gives "No i2c signal found". The wiring schematics are the same. I've tried different boards, and I've tried different code. Nothing works.

Comment: *Re: 12C gives "No i2c signal found"* The I2C (I'm guessing) can't talk. So, what exactly is reporting this message. A library? What library? Your code? What code? If you're having problems detecting I2C devices generally run the I2CScanner sketch before trying anything specific to the sensors.

Comment: When you don't give us more information, it makes it hard to help. The BME280 can use I2C OR SPI. If it is on a board set up for SPI, that might be the whole problem.....or it is something else. A picture of the board or a schematic of the circuit would help a lot.

Comment: Sorry I did not clarify. The code I was using was the 12C scanner code.

Comment: Basic debugging: try a minimal setup - connect only the BME280 to the CPU, not the other parts. Run the I2C scanner. Also let us know WHAT are you connecting it to and exactly how did you wire it?

Comment: From the datasheet "Interface selection is done automatically based on CSB (chip select) status. If CSB is connected to VDDIO, the I²C interface is active. If CSB is pulled down, the SPI interface is activated. After CSB has been pulled down once (regardless of whether any clock cycle occurred), the I²C interface is disabled until the next power-on-reset." Again, maybe show us a picture of the board or circuit?

Comment: Your image does not show VCC and GND connected to your BME280. If that's not your actual wiring, show your actual wiring.

Comment: That is the actual wiring, but the board is flipped around.

Comment: Is it a 3.3V or a 5V module?

Comment: the picture shows no power connection and no ground connection ... you are trying to *fly a rocket without an engine*

Comment: You mean that it's reversed left-to-right and that in actual use it's the CSB and SDO that are unconnected? Really you should just get a picture of it as wired so as not to confuse the crap out people.

Comment: sorry ill upload the proper picture, it all works except the pressure value is off the charts.

Answer (score 1):

@ModelRocketeer - I appreciate your frustration and I hope this will be of some help.

First of all, you have to make sure the board is wired correctly and it is anyone's guess whether it is wired correctly because you have not shown that to us and that frustrates us because we would like to help.

Here is a *very* similar board attached to a D1 mini.
[image]

If I flip it over to show the signal names, AND line it up correctly, one can see how it is hooked up....or it is just confusing because it is flipped over.
[image]

- BUT why not just tell us, like this:

> ```
> D1 mini<->280
> 3.3v   <-> Vcc 
> GND    <-> GND
> D1     <-> SCL
> D2     <-> SDA
> ```

AND show us a clear picture because many eyes on it can increase the likelihood of solving the problem.

BTW: using colored leads helps with checking.

I have several of these generic 280 boards - they are cheap and when I bought mine, they were sold as BME280, but it turns out (after hours of frustration) that they were in fact BMP280. Apparently, the board can hold either. Be forewarned.

I tested my board with a D1, like yours at 3.3v, and an UNO at 5.0V and they both worked.

I then tested a known-to-be BME280 and it worked fine with the D1 mini.

In ALL cases, I was able to use a port scanner and see the I2C address (0x76).

Because you have not been able to detect any connection over I2C for the board but can detect a port for the MPU6050, I think you need to do the following:

Make sure you have the proper connections.

Remove the MPU6050 and have only the BMP/BME connected and run the scanner.

If you *still* see nothing, I would say the board is bricked. Because you said you tested several boards, I suspect (as have others) that you do not have it connected properly.

When you get it connected properly and can see a port when scanning - try running BME software but if you use the Adafruit programs you might need to force I2C since this is not an Adafruit board. The latter is able to use both I2C and SPI.

If you still don't get results, consider that it may, in fact be a BMP280 and try software for that.

In either event, please let us know what happens.

Comment: Did you wait until I finished responding to get it to work? :)

Comment: Feels like it, but I stepped away from it for a few hours, and when I came back to it I redid everything and it "worked" though the pressure value, the only one I need is giving me an absurd value and saying I'm 32,000  feet in the air.

Comment: Yes, it can't do exact altitude on its own - see https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/44715/bmp-280-exact-altimeter-readings